# How to get a select JSON fields by name using Spring Boot WebClient?

Tags: java, json, spring

I'm using WebClient in Java to retrieve the JSON data, but I'm fairly new to JSON and Spring, so I'm not sure how to proceed from here. I want to loop through the JSON data and look for products with a ProductId containing "Clothes" and store ProductId and ProductName in a list. How do I loop through the JSON data and get check for only the field ProductId and ProductName?

```
[
{
   "ProductType": "Food",
   "ProductName": "Vineyard Tomatoes",
   "ProductId":"Food-127483"
   "InventoryCount": 128

},
{
   "ProductType": "Clothes",
   "ProductName": "Sweaters",
   "ProductId":"Clothes-2183"
   "InventoryCount": 229

},
{
   "ProductType": "Clothes",
   "ProductName": "Jeans",
   "ProductId":"Clothes-482"
   "InventoryCount": 150

}, 
{
   "ProductType": "Misc",
   "ProductName": "Clocks",
   "ProductId":"Misc-8288"
   "InventoryCount": 24

}
]


String url = inventoryURI //url to the api with the inventory data
List<Products> productList = new ArrayList<>();
WebClient webClient = WebClient.create();
Products[] product = webClient.get().uri(url)
    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .retrieve
    .bodyToMono(Products[].class)
    .block();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `spring-webflux`, you should avoid using `.block()`.

Following are some ways to retrieve field from JSON:

```
Mono<List<Products>> products = WebClient.create().get()
                                         .uri(url)
                                          .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                                          .retrieve()
                                          .bodyToMono(String.class)
                                          .map(jsonData -> {
                                           return convertJsonToProducts(jsonData);
                                        });
```

**A. Method `convertJsonToProducts` via Gson Library.**

```
public List<Products> convertJsonToProducts(String jsonData) {
    List<Products> products = new ArrayList<Products>();
    Gson gson = new Gson();  
    Products[] productArrays = gson.fromJson(jsonData, Products[].class);
    if(productArrays!=null && productArrays.length>0) {
       products = Arrays.asList(productArrays);
    } 
    return products;
}
```

*For Maven dependency of Gson Library:*

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.6</version>
</dependency>
```

**B. Method `convertJsonToProducts` via Jackson Library.**

```
public List<Products> convertJsonToProducts(String jsonData) {
    List<Products> products = new ArrayList<Products>();
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Products[] pp1 = mapper.readValue(jsonData, Products[].class);
    if(productArrays!=null && productArrays.length>0) {
       products = Arrays.asList(productArrays);
    } 
    return products;
}
```

*For Maven Dependency of Jackson Library:*

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.2</version>
</dependency>
```